# Easiest way of porting html table data to readable document

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, ms-word, reporting

Ok,

For the past 6 months i've been struggeling to build a system that allows user input in form of big sexy textareas(with loads of support for tables,list etc). Pretty much enables the user to input data as if it were word. However when wanting to export all this data I haven't been able to find a working solution...

My first step was to try and find a reporting software that did support raw HTML from the data source and render it as normal html, worked perfectly except that the keep together function is awful, either data is split in half(tables,lists etc) which I dont want. Or report always skips to the next page to avoid this, ending up in 15+ empty pages within the final document.

So Im looking for some kind of tip/direction to what would be the best solution to export my data into a readable document(pdf or word pref).

What I got is the following data breakdown, where data is often raw html.

-Period

--Unit

---Group

----Question

-----Data

What would be the best choice? Trying to render html to pdf or rtf? I need tips :(

And also sometimes the data is 2-3 pages long with mixed tables lists and plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you try to keep this in the browser, and add a [print stylesheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) to the HTML to make it render one way on the screen and [another way on paper](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/boom). Adding a print stylesheet to your HTML is as easy as this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

You should be able to parse the input it with something like [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and transform it (i.e. with [XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742.aspx)) to whatever output format you want.

Another option is to write HTML to the browser, but with `Content-Type` set to a Microsoft Word-specific variant (there are several to choose from, depending on the version of Word you're targeting) should make the browser ask if the user wants to open the page with Microsoft Word. With Word 2007 and newer you can also write [Office Open XML Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264572%28v=office.12%29.aspx) directly, since it's XML-based.

The content-types you can use are:

```
application/msword
```

For binary Microsoft Word files, but should also work for HTML.

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

For the newer "Office Open XML" formats of Word 2007 and newer.

Comment: I am using TinyMCE, its not the input thats the problem tho. Its getting a proper layout on the data when I export it. Since its raw html i cannot manually add pagebreaks and so on inside the rendering method(or maybe I can?). Its like this Say that I have data that is 60% raw text and 40% table(with text inside). The total length of the data is 3 pages. How (while rendering) can I make the data appear so that the table isnt cut at pagebreaks. This is what I'm asking for.. Passing header to word isnt rly the problem, is that the word has to be acceptable in its layout!

Comment: Sounds like what you're asking, is "how do I author Office Open XML or binary Word documents?", which reading documentation on MSDN would help to answer. Either way, parsing the input with Html Agility Pack would give you a nice Document Object Model (DOM) that you can transform into anything you want, be it a PDF document, another HTML representation, Microsoft Word or whatever. Please see my updated answer re print stylesheets, I think that's what you're after.

Comment: Did you choose the print style sheet route?

Answer (score 2):

A solution you could use is to run an application on the server using System.Diagnostics.Process that will convert the site and save it as a PDF document.

You could use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which is an open source console program that can convert from HTML to PDF or image.

The installer for windows can be obtained from [wkhtmltox-0.10.0_rc2 Windows Installer (i368)](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltox-0.10.0_rc2-installer.exe&can=3&q=).

After installing wkhtmltopdf you can copy the files in the installation folder inside your solution. You can use a setup like this in the solution:

[image]

The converted pdf's will be saved to the pdf folder.

And here is code for doing the conversion:

```
var wkhtmltopdfLocation = Server.MapPath("~/wkhtmltopdf/") + "wkhtmltopdf.exe";
var htmlUrl = @"http://stackoverflow.com/q/7384558/750216";
var pdfSaveLocation = "\"" + Server.MapPath("~/wkhtmltopdf/pdf/") + "question.pdf\"";

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = wkhtmltopdfLocation;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = htmlUrl + " " + pdfSaveLocation;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The htmlUrl is the location of the page you need to convert to pdf. It is set to this stackoverflow page. :)

Comment: im trying to test ur solution, it would be great help for me if it works..im not sure i fullt understand it,but i want to convert my .aspx to an image not an url, is it possible the same way? also i added ur code on server side into my .ashx but it seems it doesnt recognise new Process() ! is it the way its supposed to work?

Comment: @astrocybernaute: the code works, I tested it before posting cause I was curios if it is possible. It doesn't recognise Process() probably because you have not imported System.Diagnostics, to make it work add "using System.Diagnostics;"

Comment: i have added System.Diagnostics.Process, had to remove process,recognise it now :)thx.  
how about the url can i just replace it with var htmlUrl = "chartImage.aspx";

Comment: i mean this `var htmlUrl = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/chartImage.aspx");`

Comment: @astrocybernaute: yes, as long as it is a valid address it will work

Comment: its not but im working on it,thx. what do i change in ur code  if i want to convert into an image instead of a pdf?

Comment: @astrocybernaute: to save as an image you have to use wkhtmltoimage.exe instead. on this page http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/Usage in the comments (search for "The usage for wkhtmltoimage") is the list of parameters that can be used with it, for example -f sets the resulting image format

Comment: thx,if u can modify ur answer with the details we discussed and post it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293938/how-to-save-extjs4-chart-image-to-print-in-a-pdf-report) i will accept it

Answer (score 1):

Its a general question, but two things come to mind the Visitor Pattern and Changing the Mime Type.

**Visitor Pattern**
You can have two seperate rendering techniques. This would be up to your implementation.

**MIME Type**
When the request is made write date out in the Response etc

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-16";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.doc", filename));
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("-Period");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("/n");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("--Unit");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("/n");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("---Group");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("/n");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("----Question");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("/n");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("-----Data");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("/n");
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: If Data is 3 pages i would not be able to control when and where to perform a pagebreak. IE I do not want tables, lists and so to be cut in a pagebreak. (So i want there to be logic to check if the data will fit into the remaining space, otherwise do a pagebreak).

Comment: Well to the best of my knowledge you will face all sorts of these issues. Cant you render the information with something else etc Reporting Services? HTML really is designed to be displayed in a web browser.

Comment: I was trying to use Devexpress (was the only reporting software that supported HTML). We need to use html because users must be able to create tables and lists for their answers. This is what makes it so complicated...

Comment: Are they interacting with the information? Surely Word and PDF are just being used for Uni Directional rendering? I just know from previous experience when I tried to print some webpages ... it was a huge waste of time. Eventually we forced the users to use Reporting Services for anything they wanted to printout.

Comment: The system is basically a reporting page, admin ask question and users answer(in tables and lists). Then the users can print a document of all the questions and answers and show to others. And this document is where it goes wrong. Its badly formatted due to all the hard HTML. And I have no clue how to get it propperly formatted without a human hand. Few reporting services offer HTML support and im starting to figure out why, its just to hard to work with it seems :(

Comment: I had something similar but what I did was actually take print screen using WinForms Web Api in the background. It worked pretty well and comes out exactly like the user sees it. Might be worth a jam.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, use print screens (Although it doesnt take care of scrolling, I think you should be able to build this in). This example can be expanded to meet the needs of your business, although it is a hack of sorts. You pass it a URL it generates an image.

Call like this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int screenWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Request["ScreenWidth"]);
                int screenHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Request["ScreenHeight"]);
                string url =        Request["Url"].ToString();
                string bitmapName = Request["BitmapName"].ToString();


            WebURLToImage webUrlToImage = new WebURLToImage()
            {
                Url = url,
                BrowserHeight = screenHeight,
                BrowserWidth = screenWidth,
                ImageHeight = 0,
                ImageWidth = 0
            };

        webUrlToImage.GenerateBitmapForUrl();
        webUrlToImage.GeneratedImage.Save(Server.MapPath("~") + @"Images\" +bitmapName + ".bmp");
    }
```

Generate an image from a webpage.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

public class WebURLToImage
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Bitmap GeneratedImage { get; private set; }
    public int ImageWidth { get; set; }
    public int ImageHeight { get; set; }
    public int BrowserWidth { get; set; }
    public int BrowserHeight { get; set; }

    public Bitmap GenerateBitmapForUrl()
    {
        ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(ImageGenerator);
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        return GeneratedImage;
    }

    private void ImageGenerator()
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser.Navigate(Url);

        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

        while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            Application.DoEvents();
        webBrowser.Dispose();
    }

    void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
        webBrowser.ClientSize = new Size(BrowserWidth, this.BrowserHeight);
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        GeneratedImage = new Bitmap(webBrowser.Bounds.Width, webBrowser.Bounds.Height);
        webBrowser.BringToFront();

        webBrowser.DrawToBitmap(GeneratedImage, webBrowser.Bounds);

        if (ImageHeight != 0 && ImageWidth != 0)
            GeneratedImage =
(Bitmap)GeneratedImage.GetThumbnailImage(ImageWidth, ImageHeight,
null, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```