# A "shortcut" method for exporting an ASP.Net Page to pdf/xls

Tags: asp.net, excel, pdf

I want to export a few Pages to pdf/xls. By Pages I mean as the eye sees it - a screenshot of the Page's contents. I know how to build pdf/xls documents using 3rd party tools but is there any way to quickly export the rendered contents of say a `Panel`?

**edit:** maybe a tool that can render the page's output as a browser would, and save it as an image file?

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source console program named [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which you could call from asp.net to convert the page. It can convert to PDF or an image with [wkhtmltoimage](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html) (JPG, PNG, etc.) using the webkit rendering engine.

Check my answer to this question to see an example of how to convert from a html to a pdf using C#:

[Easiest way of porting html table data to readable document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384558/easiest-way-of-porting-html-table-data-to-readable-document/7386925#7386925)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend http://www.screengrab.org/ for firefox.