# how to save Extjs4 chart image to print in a pdf report?

Tags: extjs, charts, svg, itext, report

i have several charts in my extjs4application dashboard..
i want to generate a pdf report using the images of those charts
for that i use iTextSharp

**is there a way to get the images from the charts in order to include them in my report?**

the ideal for me is to use it like this with itextsharp

```
MyImageStream = new MemoryStream();
myChart.SaveImage(MyImageStream);
```

my chart would be the chart object

i asked around in the forums they told me i would generate and render my chart at client (already done) and then i would get the svg, send it to the server and server would use it to generate the pdf...
but i dont know how to work with svg neither how to send it to server

**EDIT**

im trying to use wkhtmltoimage to save my chart into image

but its not working whan i specify a mapPath to my .aspx

but it works fine if i specify a website url or localhost path (see htem in comment)

by doesnt work i mean no error but no png created!

my code:

```
var url = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/chartImage.aspx");//dosnt work
//works : // "google.com";  //"localhost/chartImage.aspx";//
        var fileName = " pie13.png ";
        var wkhtmlDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/wkhtmltopdf/pdf/");//"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\";
        var wkhtml = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltoimage.exe");//"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
        var p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = wkhtml;
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = wkhtmlDir;

        string switches = "";
        //switches += "--print-media-type ";
        //switches += "--margin-top 10mm --margin-bottom 10mm --margin-right 10mm --margin-left 10mm ";
        //switches += "--page-size Letter ";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = switches + " " + url + " " + fileName;
        p.Start();
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's a revised version after reading your comment above.
Ext JS is a client side library so you need to run it in a browser to get your charts and this can't be changed. If you really need to get these charts on the server then you must resort to some more or less dirty hacks. One of them would be:

1. Prepare a special web page that contains only the chart to be included in the PDF
2. Use wkhtmltoimage program to convert it into an image file (on the server)
3. Insert that image into PDF document using iTextSharp

But in this case I'd rather re-think the choice of tools or the way reports are generated.

Comment: im trying to convert to image with wkhtmltoimage in c# , but still not working..an u point me to how to do it plz..or maybe some documentation using c#.thank

Comment: 1. create a web page that contains your graph     2. use wkhtmltoimage command line to convert that page to an image file     3. only if you have 1 and 2 working do the same but from a C# program (invoke the wkhtmltoimage command line)

Comment: If still doesn't work then read the freaking manual and if you need more help then specify what exactly doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use wkhtmltopdf package (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert a web page with your charts into a pdf file and then let users download that pdf. In order to do that you need to run wkhtmltopdf server-side (pay attention to authentication/user impersonation).
Since wkhtmltopdf is based on Safari it should work with extjs without problems.

Comment: i already use iTextSharp and have my report all finished up excpet the charts so i dont want to change it

Answer (score 0):

I am researching about this, I think you first have to convert your chart into a picture and then use a PDF generator library and include this picture on it.
To convert chart to picture:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/charts/Area.js

To generate PDF on c# if you are using it on server side it could be pdfsharp or itext